# Area of $A:= \lbrace (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x^2+(e^x +y)^2\leq1 \rbrace$

Tags: area, multiple-integral, fubini-tonelli-theorems

I am having trouble calculating the area of $$A:= {\lbrace(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x^2+(e^x +y)^2\leq1 \rbrace}.$$ I hope someone can help me.

I have tried using Fubini with the following boundaries for $x$ and $y$:

$$-1\le x\le1 ,$$ and $$-\sqrt{1-x^2}-e^x\le y\le\sqrt{1-x^2}-e^x.$$

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please add context (homework?) and include what have you tried. Otherwise someone is likely to down-vote/close...

Comment: This seems reasonable. Write down the integral, and show us which step did you have issues with.

Comment: I got to the integral from -1 to 1 of 2*(sqrt(1-x^2)-e^x)dx and then I am stuck

Comment: Your answer (in the comments) has an algebra error - do it more slowly, and you will see that there is no $e^x$. You should recognize the integral as the area of a disc of radius 1 -  i.e., @J.G.'s answer below.  But! you can evaluate the integral with a trig. substitution.

Comment: Thank you. I did it again and I got the same result as below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Cavalieri's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavalieri%27s_principle). The area is $\int_{-1}^12\sqrt{1-x^2}dx$, just like the circle we'd get without the $e^x$ term, i.e. $\pi$.